# Removing HTML Element by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to remove an element from the DOM tree:

```
 function onItemDeleted(name) {

           $("#" + name).remove();                       

       }
```

Would this be bad for performance since I am not indicating any parent for the element. The element is a TR contained in a TABLE element. The DOM search for this element will start at the top which might be BODY. So would it be something like this:

BODY => DIV => TABLE => TR (found)

If I find the parent of TR which is TABLE would the search be like this:

TABLE -> TR

I don't know if above will be true since I think search will always start at the root node.

Comment: Do you experience any performance issues?

Comment: No I don't experience any performance issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery optimises for ID searches. So, `$("#" + name)` is effectively the same as `$(document.getElementById(name))`. From the [source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js), line 120 (1.4):

```
// HANDLE: $("#id")
} else {
    elem = document.getElementById( match[2] );
```

Comment: I think it will make more sense to hold the parent when performing a lot of deletes in a short period of time. Since, then we don't have to search the DOM tree for the element again and again.

Comment: Incidentally it's not *quite* the same as `getElementById`, because a `.` or `:` character inside the ID (which are both valid) would break the selector version.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in performance would likely be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you find elements by ID, the lookup time should be `O(1)` since there can be only one element with that ID.