# Hide HTML element by id

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hopefully there's a quick and dirty way to remove the "Ask Question" (or hide it) from a page where I can only add CSS and Javascript:

```
  <div class="nav" style="float: right;">
      <ul>
          <li style="margin-right: 0px;" >
              <a id="nav-ask" href="/questions/ask">Ask Question</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I can't hide the `nav` class because other page elements use it.

Can I hide the link element via the `nav-ask` id?

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate of, but is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262115/removing-html-element-by-id

Comment: # represents ID and . represents class, so .nav would target your class="nav" element and #nav-ask would target your id="nav-ask" element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  #nav-ask{ display:none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 138):

If you want to do it via javascript rather than CSS you can use:

```
var link = document.getElementById('nav-ask');
link.style.display = 'none'; //or
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

depending on what you want to do.

Comment: What's the difference between `display = 'none'` and `visibility = 'hidden'` though?

Comment: `display = 'none'` means that the element is effectively not on the page so no space is allocated to it on the page (you can still access via DOM) but `visibility = 'hidden'` means that space is still taken up as the element is still rendered but it's just not shown.

Answer (score 7):

@Adam Davis, the code you entered is actually a jQuery call. If you already have the library loaded, that works just fine, otherwise you will need to append the CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #nav-ask{ display:none; }
</style>
```

or if you already have a "hideMe" CSS Class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if(document.getElementById && document.createTextNode)
    {
        if(document.getElementById('nav-ask'))
        {
            document.getElementById('nav-ask').className='hideMe';
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.nav ul li a#nav-ask{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I think he wanted to do this on call, as opposed to all the time (could be wrong), but instead of: ".nav ul li a#nav-ask", just do "#nav-ask"

Answer (score 3):

I found that the following code, when inserted into the site's footer, worked well enough:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#nav-ask").remove();
</script>
```

This may or may not require jquery.  The site I'm editing has jquery, but unfortunately I'm no javascripter, so I only have a limited knowledge of what's going on here, and the requirements of this code snippet...

Comment: remove removes it. Not hides it. Use $("#nav-ask").hide();

Comment: Without using a JavaScript framework like jQuery, the code would be: document.getElementById('nav-ask').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS selectors

```
a[href="/questions/ask"] { display:none; }
```